# Cannot Add Menu Launcher With Menulibre

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

I'm admittedly new to the Ubuntu Dash, but I for the life of me can not seem to add an application to it.  I can create the launcher and save it (apparently) in Menulibre, where I simply added it to the accessories category.  However it never shows up in the Dash searching menu, and the entry vanishes completely upon reboot.  Can anyone help with this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`menulibre` doesn't supports `*.desktop` files. Therefore nothing is displayed in Unity.

Try arronax

```
sudo apt-add-ppa ppa:diesch/testing 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install arronax
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

MenuLibre works just fine. You have to make sure your command-script.sh file is executable first. Run the following in your terminal:

```
    sudo chmod +x command-script.sh
```